# Manga where the Main Character's master is a dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga years ago and I can’t find it or its name. All I remember is that the main character’s master was a dragon that can also has a human form.  During one of the chapters main character shaves off a horn of his master to sell it for money.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [4 Cut Hero](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=124028)

The chapter you mention it is chapter 39. He cut his master horn once and now he do it again.

His master is a dragon and can turn to any human form.

Picture when he do it 2nd time
[image]